# React too many re-renders when create an array with UseState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create a quiz to return the data based on selected checkboxes, the best option I find to do it is creating an array with index of every selected items but when I try to render page I receive the error of too many re-renders.

I have a JSON with some questions and the answers and I'm tryng to retrieve the list index of all selected answers and after compare with my JSON to return the right answer.

```
import "./questions.scss";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";

export default function Questions({ data }) {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const radiosWrapper = useRef();
  const [updateCheckedState, setUpdateCheckedState] = useState([]);
  const [temperament, SetTemperament] = useState("");
  console.log(updateCheckedState);

  useEffect(() => {
    radiosWrapper.current.querySelectorAll("input:checked").forEach((el) => (el.checked = false));
  }, [data]);

  const changeHandler = (position) => {
    if (!updateCheckedState.includes(position)) {
      setUpdateCheckedState((arr) => [...arr, position]);
    } else if (updateCheckedState.includes(position)) {
      const index = updateCheckedState.indexOf(position);
      setUpdateCheckedState(updateCheckedState.splice(index, 1));
    }

    const sanguine = data.sanguine.filter((e) => updateCheckedState.includes(e));
    const choleric = data.choleric.filter((e) => updateCheckedState.includes(e));
    const melancholic = data.melancholic.filter((e) => updateCheckedState.includes(e));
    const phlegmatic = data.phlegmatic.filter((e) => updateCheckedState.includes(e));

    const result = Math.max(sanguine.length, choleric.length, melancholic.length, phlegmatic.length);

    switch (result) {
      case sanguine.length:
        SetTemperament("/sanguine");
        break;
      case choleric.length:
        SetTemperament("/choleric");
        break;
      case melancholic.length:
        SetTemperament("/melancholic");
        break;
      case phlegmatic.length:
        SetTemperament("/phlegmatic");
        break;
      default:
    }

    if (error) {
      setError("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-content">
        <div className="content">
          <h2 className="mb-5">{data.question}</h2>
          <div className="control" ref={radiosWrapper}>
            {data.choices.answer.map((choice, i) => (
              <label className="radio has-background-light" key={i}>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value={choice} onChange={changeHandler(i)} />
                {choice}
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
          {error && <div className="has-text-danger">{error}</div>}
          <Link className="link" to={temperament}>
            Resultado
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does the error provide any kind of stack trace so we can trace to a line of the code?

Comment: You really should not use `querySelectorAll` when working with React...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the following line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer" value={choice} onChange={changeHandler(i)} />
```

You are invoking the function instead you should pass in a function as shown below.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="answer" value={choice} onChange={() => changeHandler(i)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The rerender bug is caused, like Som Shekhar Mukherjee pointed out, by the fact you're calling `changeHandler` during render, since it's not wrapped in a function.

Your code could be simplified a bunch, though, by noting that the `temperament` is a pure derivation of `checked` and `data`, i.e. a prime candidate for `useMemo`.

Also, it's better to use the `checked` prop for the checkboxes, so your state can never be out of sync with what the browser is showing:

```
import "./questions.scss";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";

function computeTemperament(data, checked) {
  const temperamentCounts = {};
  // Count the number of times each temperament is checked
  ["sanguine", "phlegmatic", "melancholic", "choleric"].forEach((temperament) => {
    temperamentCounts[temperament] = data[temperament].filter(e => checked.includes(e)).length;
  });
  // Find the temperament with the highest count
  return Object.keys(temperamentCounts).reduce((a, b) =>
    temperamentCounts[a] > temperamentCounts[b] ? a : b
  );
}

export default function Questions({ data }) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked([]);
  }, [data]);

  const changeHandler = React.useCallback((position) => {
    if (!checked.includes(position)) {
      setChecked((checked) => [...checked, position]);
    } else {
      setChecked((checked) => checked.filter((item) => item !== position));
    }
  }, []);

  const temperament = React.useMemo(() => computeTemperament(data, checked), [data, checked]);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-content">
        <div className="content">
          <h2 className="mb-5">{data.question}</h2>
          <div className="control">
            {data.choices.answer.map((choice, i) => (
              <label className="radio has-background-light" key={i}>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="answer"
                  value={choice}
                  checked={checked.includes(i)}
                  onChange={() => changeHandler(i)}
                />
                {choice}
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
          <Link className="link" to={temperament}>
            Resultado
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```